# PySpark Structured Streaming: Pass output of Query to API endpoint

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following dataframe in Structured Streaming:

```
TimeStamp|Room|Temperature|
00:01:29 | 1  | 55        | 
00:01:34 | 2  | 51        | 
00:01:36 | 1  | 56        | 
00:02:03 | 2  | 49        |
```

I am trying to detect when temperatures fall below a certain temperature (50 in this case). I have that part of the query working. Now, I need to pass this information to an API endpoint via a POST call like this: '/api/lowTemperature/' with the timestamp and the temperature in the body of the request. So, in the above case, I need to send along:

```
POST /api/lowTemperature/2
BODY: { "TimeStamp":"00:02:03",
       "Temperature":"49" }
```

Any idea how I can achieve this using PySpark?

One way I thought of doing this was using Custom streaming sink, but, I can't seem to find any documentation on achieving this using Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news, as support for Python has recently been added for the ForeachWriter.  I created one in Python for REST and Azure Event Grid and it's rather straightforward.
The (basic) documentation, can be found here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/foreach.html#using-python

Answer (score 2):

At the time of my original response, [ForeachWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreach) was only supported for Java/Scala, however, it now supports [Python](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.foreach) as well.

Make sure you read the section on execution semantics and understand how to avoid duplicate API calls if that's an issue.